# Custom SQL code for custom field type in Django migration

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

My project contains a large number of tables which have timestamp fields `created_at`, and `updated_at`, which signify, respectively, when the row was created, and most recently modified.

Each time I create a new model with these fields, I add the following `RunSQL` statement to the migration:

```
migrations.RunSQL('CREATE TRIGGER some_trigger_name BEFORE UPDATE ON my_table FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE update_modified_column()');
```

A large number of database operations happen outside of Django, so it's necessary to track this in the database layer, as opposed to just using `updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)` when defining the model.

Is it possible to create a custom field type, which when I run the `makemigrations` command, will automatically generate that `RunSQL` statement?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Automatically generate custom migrations in Django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49297630/automatically-generate-custom-migrations-in-django)